# Can browse internet, cannot ping / update / install anything

Tags: software-center, internet, proxy, ping

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10, but I cannot update softwares. Not even from Ubuntu Software center. I have proxy applied system wide. Here are a few screenshots. Thanking in advance.

[image]

[image]

```
sudo apt-get update
```

is returning me
[image]

Moreover in Ubuntu Software Center I don't have any install button, instead I have "Use this as source".
[image]

Even Ubuntu Web Browser doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: Do you need to use a username/password with the proxy?

Comment: See: [can not ping google using proxy](http://askubuntu.com/questions/428408/can-not-ping-google-using-proxy)

Comment: Are you sure that in proxy server there is not blocked ICMP or only just allowed ports 80/443/22

Comment: Basically you can't ping behind a proxy and that's normal..  But the software updates should work.

Comment: even after "export http_proxy..." i am unable to ping google.

Comment: Are you able to ping ip address instead of domain name? for example: ping 8.8.8.8 does this work for you?

Comment: No ping 8.8.8.8 returns the same thing as ping google.com