# does ping work behind squid proxy?

Tags: networking, server, dns, proxy, squid

I wonder if it is possible to use ping command behind a proxy?
I'm really confused because this page says:
[how does ping work over proxy?](https://superuser.com/questions/1002281/how-does-ping-work-over-a-proxy)
that it is not possible to use ping command behind proxy.

but this page says  [can not ping google using proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428408/can-not-ping-google-using-proxy)
it is possible.

which one is correct? I also must mention that curl and wget work correctly but ping doesn't work at all. I also have to add that the only way that I can access to internet is through proxy.
is there setting in squid to let the ICMP pass through

Comment: Did you try `httping` mentioned in an answer in your second link? Ping itself uses another IP protocol (not TCP) and will not work through a proxy, even a socks proxy.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli no i didn’t. the point is that there are other servers  can ping correctly and they use this proxy server too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Squid will not proxy ICMP traffic.  If the network you are on prohibits ICMP, then you will need to ssh to some other machine that is permitted to send/receive ICMP traffic.

Comment: could you please give me a reference ?

Comment: From the Squid docs (http://www.squid-cache.org/Intro/):

```Squid is a fully-featured HTTP/1.0 proxy which is almost (but not quite - we're getting there!) a fully-featured HTTP/1.1 proxy. Squid offers a rich access control, authorization and logging environment to develop web proxy and content serving applications. Squid offers a rich set of traffic optimization options, most of which are enabled by default for simpler installation and high performance.```

... Squid is an HTTP proxy, while ICMP is at a lower level of the protocol stack.